# How to plot functions like $\min\{x+y,4\sqrt x,4\sqrt y\}$?

Tags: optimization, graphing-functions

Do I plot it like a regular $\min\{x,y\} $function, where I equate $x=y$ and get the $45$ degree line and then plot the two hands ? In this type, should I equate the equations pairwise ? But then that becomes very confusing .. Please help .

Comment: It contains $x+y$, how could you plot $x+y$ in 2d plane??

Comment: I'll equate x+y to any value for example x+y=1 (say) then plot that

Comment: That is $\min \{ 4\sqrt{x},4\sqrt{y} \}$ under constraint $x+y=1$, not $\min\{x+y,4\sqrt x,4\sqrt y\}$

Comment: So do I equate the entire equation to any number , say 4 , then equate the individual equations inside the min function to 4 [x+y=4 , 4√x=4, 4√y=4] , then plot these three and then highlight/ take the min portion of the combined graph ?

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use a [3d surface plot](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Min%5Bx%2By,4*Sqrt%5Bx%5D,4*Sqrt%5By%5D%5D)?

Comment: But how do I plot the real part on a paper ?

Comment: According to the wolfram software [the link provided above] this graph has a real part and an imaginary part